# Windows Phone 8.1 break point error

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-express

I have a big problem with the break points on visual studio express.

If I set a break point and debug on the emulator, it works and I can step into the code.
But if I debug on the device, the red round becomes white and says: "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document".

I need to debug on device because on the emulator all work well but on the device i have some problem who I should fix..

Anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Are you using the Debug build on the device?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the symbols you have do not match the binary you're trying to debug. Try uninstalling the app you're debugging from the device and then running the debugger again. There is also an option in the Visual Studio project properties that will force redeployment of the app every time you debug. Normally, I wouldn't turn on that option because it will uninstall and reinstall the app everytime (when debugging) thus losing you any data the app might have saved to it's local storage. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are usnig the release option to run your application! There is a dropdown menu on the right side of your device list where you cna change your run settings. To debug your application, you need to select the "Debug" option.

[image: This is where you need to select Debug]